# AXRuntimeCommon AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:503

Tags: ios, swift

**I am getting below error when i trying to login with Google. I am implementing login with google functionality. i am getting google popup two times after that got user login detail.**

```
[AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied 
portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:503 (
0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ae2cd228 E4B5B0DA-13CE-3404-8E9F-17649C25CF1B + 303656
1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ae286b58 _AXGetPortFromCache + 696
2   AXRuntime                           0x00000001ae28820c AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 484
3   UIKit                               0x00000001df59e444 510684E1-8A80-36A8-A20C-42E5C9BAC134 + 885828
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ff0718 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ff1f94 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ff9150 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 684
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ff9dd4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 432
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001020054e8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 852
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001df292e84 _pthread_wqthread + 284
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001df2929f0 start_wqthread + 8
```

)

**Also my OpenUrl delegate function is not calling.**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, 
options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.